# Css relative responsive height

Tags: html, css

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I want to have the child to have the height of the parent minus the margins. Why is the height 0px?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3rLgza5/28/)

Comment: display:flex to parent?

Answer (score 0):

`height: auto` is just "automatically as large as it should be for the content it contains."  If you want to explicitly make it the height minus the margins, you can set `height: calc(100% - 20px);`:

```css
#parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#child {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```